# Jquery change form action on on drop down change

Tags: jquery

I am having an issue getting my below jquery to work. When I test it the form is not updating nor is the alert being triggered yet I have jquery on the page that works fine for a slider etc.I also do not see any errors in the console. My form has an id for form1 and my dropdown has an id of LoginTo

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#loginTo").change(function() {
    var url = jQuery(this).children(":selected").text(); //get the selected option value
    switch (url) {
      case "Personal":
        alert('Login Down For Maintenance');

        jQuery("#form1").attr('action', 'https://fred.flinstone.com');
        //changing action attribute of form
        break;
      case "Business":
        alert('Business Login Down For Maintenance');
        jQuery("#form1").attr('action', 'https://wilma.flinstone.com');
        break;
      default:
        jQuery("#form1").attr('action', '#');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <select id="loginTo">
      <option value="" selected="selected" hidden="">Select account type</option>
      <option valuw="Personal">Personal account</option>
      <option value="Business">Business account</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group"><input name="myname" placeholder="Username" autocomplete="off"></div>
  <div class="form-group"><input name="mypass" type="password" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off"></div>
  <div class="form-group"><input class="login__btn blue" type="submit" value="Sign in"></div>
  <a class="login__btn" href="">Enroll Me Today</a>
</form>
```

Comment: Also you should set a reasonable value to the options and use this. What if your application becomes translated to another language ? Then your code must be changed everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use

```
$(this).val();
```

Instead of this children stuff

And take care you have a typo at the personal option „valuw“